# Overwrite postLogin function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

im trying to overwrite postLogin function on my laravel App, but is giving me a `"Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist"`. Basically before i put the function postLogin it never gave me this error, the login works fine,but now that im trying to overwrite the postLogin function since i need to insert some more logic, is giving me the error.
My laravel version is 5.2

Here is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/admin/';


    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }



    /**
     * Overwrite postLogin function.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'passwords' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'passwords' => bcrypt($data['passwords']),
        ]);
    }






}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `postLogin()` is trying to inject `Request` class, but you've forgot to define it's namespace.

Add this line right after `namespace` clause at the top of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to `use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`

you should build a trait some where in your code and paste all code from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` to the new trait; then add your logic to the new trait.